# Copy Paste through function is not working

Tags: excel, excel-2007, formula, vba

If the Column A cell value is pass then Column B cell value should be moved to Column C.

E.g:

When Column `A=fail`

```
Column A   Column B Column C
Fail       123        blank
Fail       345        blank
```

When Column A=Pass

```
Column A    Column B Column C
Pass        blank    123  
Pass        blank    345
```

I have used following code, but while i ma executing i am getting '0' result.

```
Function MoveA(Status)
   Call Copy1(Status)
   Application.Run "Copy1"
End Function

Sub Copy1(Status)
   If (Status = "pass") Then
     Range("B3").Copy
     Range("C3").Select

     ActiveSheet.Paste
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you writing the MoveA Formula? in cell D3?

Comment: `Range("B3").Cut Range("C3")` (but it sounds like you should turn this into a loop)  However, you can do this easily with a simple formula without using VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to use any code at all, just formulas.

If you paste the formula `=IF(A2="pass", B2, "")` into `cell C2` and *copy down* it should work for you.